# Sitecore: Linking(in RTE) to "proxyfied" media items

Tags: sitecore

In the Rich Test Editor, when linking to a proxy item referencing a media item using "Insert Sitecore Link", the link does not behave correctly, as it links to the proxy item directly, instead of the the proper resource in the media library.

Eg. when link is clicked, the user gets a "broken" proxy page, instead of the link is treated as the correct resource type.

RTE "Insert Sitecore Link" -> Proxy folder/subitems -> Media Library folder/subitems

Question: Are there some way of "extending" the proxy functionality, to properly support linking proxyfied Media Library items?

Comment: What's your question? This looks more like a bug report you should discuss with Sitecore support :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitecore gives you the ability to create a `custom link provider` in which you can override the method `GetItemUrl`. GetItemUrl is called when internal links in the RTE link are expanded in to 'a' tags. You could use you custom link provider to assemble links differently when the link is set to one of your proxy items (i.e. if it's a proxy item then create link to the corresponding media item).

The following articles give examples of customizing how links are formed

- [Sitecore Custom Urls](http://thinkedynamic.com/web-strategy-3/sitecore-custom-urls)
- [Sitecore Product URLs Amazon Style](http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2011/02/sitecore-product-urls-amazon-style.html)